# In Angular 2, why does it matter where exactly in a service an array of providers is declared?

Tags: angular

I have a service (you-tube.service.ts) that gets a list of videos from YouTube. It would appear that Angular 2 is particular about where I declare an array of providers within you-tube.service.ts Here is the array...

```
export var youTubeServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
  {provide: YouTubeService, useClass: YouTubeService},
  {provide: YOUTUBE_API_KEY, useValue: YOUTUBE_API_KEY},
  {provide: YOUTUBE_API_URL, useValue: YOUTUBE_API_URL}
];
```

This is used in app.module.ts as follows...

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    YoutubeSearchComponent,
    SearchBoxComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    youTubeServiceInjectables // Used here!!!
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the code of the complete service with comments. When the array of providers is placed near the top of the file, I get a "No providers" error, but when placed near the bottom of the file, everything works just fine.

Why does it matter where exactly in the file this array of providers is placed?

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { SearchResult } from './search-result';

export var YOUTUBE_API_KEY: string = 'key here';
export var YOUTUBE_API_URL: string = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

/************************************************************************/
/* youTubeServiceInjectables declared here results in No Provider error */
/************************************************************************/
/* 
export var youTubeServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
  {provide: YouTubeService, useClass: YouTubeService},
  {provide: YOUTUBE_API_KEY, useValue: YOUTUBE_API_KEY},
  {provide: YOUTUBE_API_URL, useValue: YOUTUBE_API_URL}
];
*/

@Injectable()
export class YouTubeService {

  constructor(private http: Http,
    @Inject(YOUTUBE_API_KEY) private apiKey: string,
    @Inject(YOUTUBE_API_URL) private apiUrl: string,
  ) { }

  search(query: string): Observable<SearchResult[]> {
    let params: string = [
      `q=${query}`,
      `key=${this.apiKey}`,
      `part=snippet`,
      `type=video`,
      `maxResults=10`,
    ].join('&');
    let queryUrl:string = `${this.apiUrl}?${params}`;
    return this.http.get(queryUrl)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return (<any>response.json()).items.map(item => {
          //console.log("raw item", item); // uncomment if you want to debug
          return new SearchResult({
            id: item.id.videoId,
            title: item.snippet.title,
            description: item.snippet.description,
            thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url
          });
        });
      });

  }
}
/**************************************************/
/* youTubeServiceInjectables declared here works! */
/**************************************************/
export var youTubeServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
  {provide: YouTubeService, useClass: YouTubeService},
  {provide: YOUTUBE_API_KEY, useValue: YOUTUBE_API_KEY},
  {provide: YOUTUBE_API_URL, useValue: YOUTUBE_API_URL}
];
```

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: AFAIK, it has nothing to do with Angular. It's just that you're trying to reference the class (in the providers) before it's defined.

Comment: Is that that's the matter? Thanks.

Comment: try to use let instead of var when declaring the array